# How often do you find javascript disabled on browsers?

Tags: javascript

I have started using ajax/jQuery in our websites / application. There are many plugins that support degrading the javascript to browsers that dont have javascript enabled and techniques to support this. What are peoples thoughts on javascript support, we build applications rather than just websites and are looking to just support javascript enabled browsers as a pre-requisite assuming that most people or companies have javascript enabled.
Do you find most people have javascript? do you monitor the percentage of javascript/non-javascript browsers (I guess this can be done with website stats) and what are the numbers regarding this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether you should be worried about this really depends on what sort of website you are creating. For instance, if you're creating a rich javascript app, you have to ask yourself if it's worth your time & effort to worry about javascript disabled browsers, as these users are probably not too concerned with using rich user interfaces anyway. Also do you have time to put in the extra work for these browsers as there will be little extra traffic and profit gained (if it's profit making website).

Also note that if javascript is disabled in these user's browsers, there will be much on the web these people cannot use. So in all likelihood they're not heavy users.

Comment: How does this answer actually answer the question asked?

Answer (score 7):

According to [these metrics](http://visualrevenue.com/blog/2007/08/eu-and-us-javascript-disabled-index.html), the following percentages of users have JavaScript disabled:

- EU: 1.4%
- US: 3.05%

But the numbers are from 2007, so they are rather old. I would think the percentages are a bit smaller by now, but who knows?

Comment: I'd think they are rather larger today. See how the NoScript Firefox extension is popular.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a very old thread, but I thought I'd post this for reference:

According to [this website](http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/84-a-study-of-internet-users-cookie-and-javascript-settings), only 0.4% to 2.4% of users had JS turned off. The first test they ran was with about 13,500 users, which is admittedly small for the interwebs, but it's still quite a large amount of people. **This data is from 2009**

Answer (score 4):

I really feel quite strongly that a well designed web site should remain functional with or without JavaScript switched on. JavaScript, in most cases, is there to enhance existing functionality.

This can usually be achieved by following a few simple rules.

1. Use unobtrusive JavaScript, avoid in-line (certainly) and in-page JavaScript whenever possible.
2. Anchors should always link to somewhere, not to # or to JavaScript. If you can't get around it, the link should be created dynamically.
3. Use forms correctly. A button should always be wrapped in form tags, this way the your functionality can always degrade to the server.

I believe that following these rules makes for a more robust site that is more accessible across multiple platforms. Not to mention the benefits to search engine optimisation, if you rely on JavaScript, the search engine will only see half your site.

I prefer the idea of progressively enhancing rather than planning for degradation. I'm absolutely not developing for the minority that intentionally sabotage their Internet experience by switching JavaScript off. A site built for progressive enhancement will work better on mobile platforms, screen readers and search engines.

Rich

Comment: +1 for "I'm absolutely not developing for the minority that intentionally sabotage their Internet experience by switching JavaScript off."

Answer (score 2):

As a whole, I think you can expect any browser that supports CSS will have JavaScript enabled.

However, it's not always a question of JavaScript being enabled/disabled on the browser entirely. Most of my friends/coworkers use [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) to only allow JavaScript on specific sites.

Comment: Yep. I use noscript and allow sites on a case by case basis. Often times if a site uses JS for things like navigation I won't bother enabling it if I don't anticipate repeat visits and will just move on elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are doing.
Is it a website or web application?

A website can be done with just static html and, if needed something a little more complex, a little bit of server side programming.

A web application, today, is all about javascript.
So if your visitors have js disabled, they are likely not interested in your application nor any other. So why bother with them?

Just concentrate in the other 98%, where your potential customers/audience is.

Answer (score 1):

It deppends on the size,

- Big applications like Gmail often have 'basic html' versions to support old and secured browsers. If you code your ajax with this in mind, you might be able to reuse most of the code.
- Medium sized applications, especially if the user uses them regular, will probably not find it worthwhile to support the few percentages.
- Small sites / sites that mostly uses basic html navigation, should try to do without javascript. Most of the time, modern css tricks will do better, faster and make more sense codewise.