# PHP Form Field (display:none) Spam Prevention

Tags: php, validation, captcha, spam-prevention

I am working on the re-development of a clients website and am looking for an alternative to a captcha in order to make the user experience a little nicer. I am redeveloping the various forms throughout the site and am trying to find the best solution for preventing spam.

The clients have specified that they do not want me to use recaptcha or anything else that requires an external web service or calling any external urls, etc.

I have heard before that creating a field called 'email' for example and setting its display to 'display:none'. When the form is submitted I would then check (php) to see if the email field has a value and if so then the submission is spam and to not continue with the process.

Is this method sound? The site receives a very large amount of traffic and I assume would get a very large amount of spam without the captcha control they had been using on the previous form.

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: I had a similar problem. I think you need some sort of captcha but there are some nice alternatives to the norm. This slider is a favorite - http://theymakeapps.com/users/add

Comment: What's wrong with using re-Captcha? afterall, it's all for a good cause :-)

Comment: I have the hidden field variant on one of my sites and it was fine for a few months. Now I get about 1-3 spams/week (someone with a .pl address figured it out). If you can live with that...

Comment: @SpaceBeers nice one, I didn't know the slider take on captcha :)

Comment: @equinoxel It's cool right? I like the ones where they ask you to do an equation as well but slider is the best I've found.

Comment: Are the sliders not javascript based? What happens if javascript is turned off?

Comment: They are but when you look at the % of people who have it turned off, are you fussed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571782/how-often-do-you-find-javascript-disabled-on-browsers

Comment: Personally no I wouldn't mind too much but I think the client will. I have decided to go with a combination of the hidden field and a second step confirmation page as suggested in this article *provided by you :)  http://doteduguru.com/id3038-are-you-human-is-captcha-needed-some-alternatives.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's quite a nice article on this here - http://doteduguru.com/id3038-are-you-human-is-captcha-needed-some-alternatives.html

I think you are right to consider hidden fields. The only downside is people with CSS turned off but do you really get many of them?

The fanciest alternative I've found is the use of a slider - http://theymakeapps.com/users/add

Answer (score 0):

One method I have used in the past is to have two fields (call them whatever you want). One has a pre-set value, and the other is blank. The user just has to copy the random string over. Just make sure to check that both the values are the same, and also that the original value hasn't been changed.

Also, if you do want to implement something captcha-like without the external links, you can use the gd module in php to create the image/text.